# rsync only copy new folders and files in root directory

Tags: rsync

I am using rsync to mirror one folder to another. The source folder contains of backup folders for each day that where made with another tool, e.g.

- backup-2023-11-01
- backup-2023-11-02

Right now I am using rsync as follows:

`rsync -a -H --update --delete --progress --stats --human-readable /source/ /target`

Since each backup folder includes many folders and files the process takes very long (several days) because rsync looks into each backup folder and searches for modifications. Actually, rsync does not need to look into each backup folder to check if something changed because that does (or should) not happen. It just has to copy the new backup folders.

Some remarks to the rsync arguments I am using right now:

- `-H`: This is the main reason I am using rsync, because my backups are based on an incremental hardlink method and rsync is one of the few tools that preserve the hardlink instead of copying each link several time.
- `-delete`: The final folder structure is a bit more complicated, since daily backups are converted into weekly / monthly backups at some point and the folders are named accordingly. Therefore, some backups are deleted in the source and that should be mirrored to the target.

I did some research in the rsync documentation and tried to find answers in several forums but could not get it to work. I thought I had it when I used `--ignore-existing`, but this only skips existing files but not existing folders. The manual states that if this argument would skip existing folders nothing would be done, but this is not true in my case but would actually do what I want.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I believe hardlinking requires rsync to know about all the files - if you try to synchronise a subset, links to files outside the subset will probably not be retained

Comment: If you store all backups on ZFS, copying can be done extremely efficiently with `zfs send` / `zfs receive`. I haven't used btrfs but something similar may be possible there

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback. This might actually be true that rsync would need to know about hard links that link to somewhere outside the subset... But even if I wasn't using hard links it would be interesting if I could make rsync skip existing folders. If I could find out how, I could try if it would work with hard links as well. And using zfs is not an option because I am using a cheap QNAP NAS that does not support that file system. But if there are any alternatives to using rsync that also support retaining hard links I would try them out as well.

Comment: if your qnap uses lvm, it looks like it is possible to copy snapshots at that level - eg. https://github.com/mpalmer/lvmsync

Comment: also: https://github.com/davidbartonau/lvm-thin-sendrcv and https://github.com/smemsh/baksync and perhaps: https://github.com/tasket/wyng-backup

Comment: I had a look at the snapshot capabilities but sadly I configured "static volume" instead of thick- or thin-volume and the system tells me that snapshots are not supported for static volumes.

Answer (score 0):

Pre-creating hardlinks might be fast enough.

---

quick&dirty proof-of-concept:

- create initial main hardlink map
- do normal rsync of first directory
- for each directory subsequently added:

  - create incremental hardlink map
  - compare incremental against main, and create missing links
  - do normal rsync of that directory
  - update main map from incremental

```
# create test directories

mksrc_a(){
    mkdir -p src/a
    echo a   >src/a/f1
    echo abc >src/a/f2
    echo a   >src/a/f3
}
mksrc_b(){
    mkdir -p src/b
    echo b   >src/b/f4
    echo bc  >src/b/f5
    ln src/a/f2 src/b/f6
}
mksrc_c(){
    mkdir -p src/c
    ln src/a/f2 src/c/f7
    ln src/b/f5 src/c/f8
    echo c   >src/c/f9
}

# helper functions
mkmap()(cd src; find $1 -type f -printf '%i %p\n')
mklinks()(
    awk '
        NR==FNR { i[$1] = $2; next }
        $1 in i { print i[$1],$2 }
    ' main.map incr.map | (
        cd dst
        while read to from; do
            mkdir -p $(dirname $from)
            ln $to $from
        done
    )
)
```

```
mksrc_a
mkdir dst
mkmap a > main.map
rsync -iaxHAX src/a dst/
```

```
mksrc_b
mkmap b >incr.map
mklinks
rsync -iaxHAX src/b dst/
cat incr.map >>main.map
```

```
mksrc_c
mkmap c >incr.map
mklinks
rsync -iaxHAX src/c dst/
cat incr.map >>main.map
```

```
# check results
for d in src dst; do
    ( cd $d; find . -type f -printf '%i %p\n' )
done |
sort |
awk '
    { i[$1]=i[$1] OFS $2 }
    END { for (s in i) print i[s] }
' |
sort |
uniq -c
```

Obviously, for actual use, one would implement this much more carefully.

Comment: for efficiency, one might want `find` to use `-links +1` to exclude uninteresting files but this is tricky to get right (as adding to code above should demonstrate - the links will not be created correctly with that addition)

Comment: reordering **might** work: `mksrc_a; rsync` / `mksrc_b; mkmap a >>main; mkmap b >incr; mklinks; rsync` / `mksrc_c; mkmap b>>main; mkmap c >incr; mklinks; rsync` / etc

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed information! This exceeds my abilities but I will study your code and try to understand and implement it!

Comment: have fun. note that this code is just to demonstrate the concept that with certain assumptions (such as old backups not changing) faster partial/incremental transfers can probably be done with rsync if the hardlinks are transferred separately. backups must be reliable to be useful. slow but working code beats fast and buggy.